# Library Design: Procedural vs OOP

Tags: c, oop

I'm weighing the differences in performance between the following, and I might have some shortcoming on my understanding of the compiler. From my understanding:

```
typedef struct{
    void (*foo)();
} Foo;
```

Would allocate enough space for a pointer every time it is declared.

This leads me to design functions like this:

```
void foo(Foo*);
```

Is this an unnecessary optimization?

Comment: By some definition, all optimisation is unnecessary if not bottlenecked. But I'd say personally to use the 2nd style unless there's some need for the 1st. Even if not a bottleneck, I don't see the tiny emulation of actual OOP syntax you get in the 1st, to be worth storing anything extra, versus just explicitly passing a `this` pointer as in the 2nd. Note also that if the 1st option needed the instance, it would _also_ need to pass it. So it stores an unneeded pointer AND still has to pass the `Foo*` anyway. But: that's probably just my opinion, and/or depends on more concrete context not shown

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a second set of eyes on this.

Comment: A broad discussion about paradigms and best practices may be more at home at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that the OP didn't ask about style but about performance, which is on topic.

Comment: Generally IMO if you want OOP the C++ is your friend. It is quite easy to use C libraries and code in the C++ program (the opposite is a bit more complicated, but not impossible)

Comment: Ironically enough, I'm actually refactoring a code base I originally wrote in PHP, translated to C++, and now am trying my hand at C. I found that the amount of abstraction in C++ left me completely oblivious to the sheer amount of memory my project was consuming.

Comment: Your code base already suffered a programming language change, isn't it possible that what it needs now is a refactor to a more modern C++ version and maybe some different design choices, before going with another language shift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with function pointers to emulate C++-like syntax is not so much that you need to pass on the "this" object through a parameter, but rather that you rather drastically block the compiler's chances of inlining those member function calls.

OO design isn't about using a particular syntax, but about program design. So if you can do with `foo_set(&foo)` instead of `foo.set(&foo)`, the former is likely to result in much more efficient code. Particularly when calling simple "setter/getter" functions from inside the "class" translation unit itself.

Also please note that `void (*foo)();` is obsolete style in C and you should be writing `void (*foo)(void);` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I figured inlining was part of the problem in this case - that's why I was specifically citing my knowledge gaps in compiler design. Will the compiler disregard all pointers when inlining, or does it depend on how many levels of indirection?

Comment: @EvanHendler Object pointers as part of the parameter list "disappear" during inlining just as any other parameter. The issue here is that compilers can generally not inline function calls through function pointers, which isn't related to what parameters you use, but the run-time nature of function pointers.

Comment: Ok, that was in line with what I was thinking, no pun intended. Just needed a dummy check.

Comment: Basically during runtime, the address of the function gets assigned to the pointer, and then when you call a function pointer, it is dereferencing the pointer and calling the function.

Comment: If inlined, it would defeat the entire purpose, because now the function pointer is static.